# sIFR, text keeps overlapping the SWF object

Tags: sifr

I'm trying to get sIFR to work but this seems to be a harder job than remembering PI to the 50th number behind the comma...

After a lot of puzzling I got my font displayed on the site but no matter what I try the original heading1 text is not replaced. In fact the created SWF is placed behind the H1-tag.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. Due to a bug in my template parser the 'screen' css file wasn't included!